# Building a PNPM monorepo with Webpack - builds too large?

Tags: javascript, webpack, frontend, monorepo, pnpm

I have a PNPM monorepo that has a couple of different deployments and a large package with shared code including many dependencies (for example BigNumber.js).

The monorepo projects are:

1. shared utility package
2. server
3. serverless API (many Lambda functions, built with Webpack)
4. web client (MPA, built with Webpack)

My problem is that some of the builds are larger than I believe they should be. For example, some Lambda functions and web pages contain ~3 MBs of minified JavaScript whereas they should be less than 1 MB.

I believe this may be because Webpack is not properly removing unused dependencies of the shared package.

How should a project like this be set up?
Am I doing something wrong?
How can I keep the builds small without moving all the code back into a single project and losing my monorepo advantages?

I've tried switching the shared package between ESM and CJS, and both, and making some changes to the Webpack config, however none of these seem to make much difference.

Answer (score 0):

Try to upgrade to pnpm [v7.29.0](https://github.com/pnpm/pnpm/releases/tag/v7.29.0). Then add these settings to the `.npmrc` in the root of your project or workspace:

```
dedupe-peer-dependents=true
auto-install-peers=true
```

NOTE: These settings are true by default already in pnpm v8.0.0-beta.0

Then remove `pnpm-lock.yaml`, `node_modules`, and run `pnpm install`.

You should get less packages in your lockfile.

After that you can also try to run [pnpm dedupe](https://pnpm.io/cli/dedupe), which might reduce the number of dependencies further. But this is optional and probably won't make a huge difference.